# How to use the contents of a field in an SQL table as HTML

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to use the contents of a field in an SQL table as HTML. The table field contains HTML.

TABLE NAME: "destination"
HTML code stored in column called: "post"
Table primary key: "destId"

My PhP code (inside PhP tags of course:

```
// Selects the post from destinations table
$sql = "SELECT post FROM `destination` WHERE destiD = 1;"; //SQL Query
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query

echo $result; // Inserts HTML
```

Error received:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
> converted to string in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\travel\including\destinations\1-London.php on line 6

Comment: You can't retrieve result like this. Use [mysqli-result functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).

Comment: `$result` is a object resource not a string to print/echo it , you need to fetch the result set to print the values

Answer (score 3):

`$result` is a object resource not a string to print/echo it , you need to fetch the result set to print the values

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['post'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$result is an array, you should try to convert it with a loop

```
for($result as $x){
    echo $x;
}
```

Comment: that should be foreach() btw my mistake, I'm used to java. anyway you should indeed use mysqli_fetch too on result. like mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query

echo $result; // Inserts HTML
```

Thats not correct, you have to use [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) first:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $array['post']; // Inserts HTML
```